# Renaming a handlebarsjs variable in the template

Tags: typescript, handlebars.js

Hello I'm trying to rename variables in a handlebars template, for example

```
const template = `{{#if true}}
This is {{FOO.FOO}}:
- {{BAR.FOO}}
- {{QUX.BAZ}}
{{/if}}`;

const template = renameVariable("FOO", "DOG", template)

/*
template is now
{{#if true}}
This is {{DOG.FOO}}:
- {{BAR.FOO}}
- {{QUX.BAZ}}
{{/if}}
*/
```

I tried to use `Handlebars.parseWithoutProcessing` which returns the blocks, but it seems there are so many use cases to cover (properties equal to parent object, `ContentStatement` equal to the property we want to rename, etc.), I was wondering if there was a built-in way to do this or any helpers?

I'll still include my current code, which does not work yet:

```
export const renameHandlebarsVariables = (
    oldName: string, newName: string, prompt: string,
): string => {
  const program = getHandlebarsVariables(prompt);
  const lengthDiff = newName.length - oldName.length;
  program.body.forEach((variable) => {
    if (variable.type === "BlockStatement") {
      const bs = variable as hbs.BlockStatement;
      const pe = bs.params[0] as hbs.SubExpression;
      pe.params.forEach((param) => {
        const p = param as hbs.PathExpression;
        if (p.parts[0] !== oldName) return;
        // param.loc.line represents the number of line breaks
        // so offsetStart is the number of characters before the first line
        const offsetStart = findNthOccur(prompt, "\n",
            param.loc.start.line - 1);
        const offsetEnd = findNthOccur(prompt, "\n",
            param.loc.end.line - 1);
        const start = offsetStart + param.loc.start.column;
        const end = offsetEnd + param.loc.end.column;
        prompt = prompt.slice(0, start) +
          prompt.slice(start).replace(
              oldName,
              newName
          ) +
          prompt.slice(end + lengthDiff + 1);
      });

      bs.program.body.forEach((variable2) => {
        if (variable2.type === "ContentStatement") return;
        const ms = variable2 as hbs.MustacheStatement;
        const path = ms.path as hbs.PathExpression;
        if (path.parts[0] !== oldName) return;
        const offsetStart = findNthOccur(prompt, "\n",
            path.loc.start.line - 1);
        const offsetEnd = findNthOccur(prompt, "\n",
            path.loc.end.line - 1);
        const start = offsetStart + path.loc.start.column;
        const end = offsetEnd + path.loc.end.column;
        prompt = prompt.slice(0, start) +
          prompt.slice(start).replace(
              oldName,
              newName
          ) +
          prompt.slice(end + lengthDiff + 1);
      });
    }
  });

  return prompt;
};
```

Also, I can't deny I'm a bit confused by column/line thing of handlebars

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any way to do this and I am having difficulty imagining what the benefit of it would be. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: The user is editing the properties name being used in the template, I want to automatically update the template accordingly

Comment: I'm not sure why/how the user is modifying property names, but I suspect that a better approach would be to map whatever the user is supplying to a well-defined object whose schema is compatible with the template. Dynamically rewriting the template seems to me to be neither practical nor wise.